# My dynamically created movie clips are not going away

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a breakout type game with dynamically-created squares.  When a brick gets hit, I fire off a removeMC function that is supposed to turn it white and make it shrink down in size.  However, sometimes the squares just turn white instead of tweening down.  I have included the script for the removeMV function as well as the function that creates the squares.  Arg1 is the square to be removed.  I apologize for the bad naming conventions, but the fire got corrupted and had to be recovered with a decompiler.

This is the removeMC function

```
  public function removeMC(arg1:flash.display.Sprite):*
    {
       this.score --;
        this.uiBar.txtScore.text=this.score;
        var loc1:*=new flash.geom.ColorTransform();
        loc1.color = 0xffffFF;
        arg1.transform.colorTransform = loc1;
        TweenMax.to(arg1, 0.4, {colorTransform:{tint:0x0000ff, tintAmount:1}});
        var loc2:*=this.ballMC.x - this.ballMC.x % 30;
        var loc3:*=this.ballMC.y - this.ballMC.y % 30;
        arg1.scaleY = arg1.scaleY * -1;
       // trace("Ball x:" + this.ballMC.x + " ballY:" + this.ballMC.y + " block x:" +     loc2 + " block y:" + loc3);
        var loc4:*=new fl.transitions.Tween(arg1, "width", null, 30, 0, 0.5, true);
        var loc5:*=new fl.transitions.Tween(arg1, "height", null, 30, 0, 0.5, true);
        var loc6:*=new fl.transitions.Tween(arg1, "x", null, 0, loc2, 0.5, true);
        var loc7:*=new fl.transitions.Tween(arg1, "y", null, 0, loc3, 0.5, true);
        this.brickArray.splice(this.indexSearch(this.brickArray, arg1), 1);
        arg1.x+=3000;//failsafe to remove the squares.  doesn't work
        arg1.y+=3000;
        return;
    }
```

This is the function that creates the squares.  Arg 1 and arg2 are the width and height in squares

```
     public function createImgNodeGrid(arg1:int=1, arg2:int=1, arg3:Number=0):void
    {
        var loc6:*=0;
        var loc7:*=null;
        var loc8:*=null;
        var loc9:*=null;
        var loc10:*=null;
        var loc1:*=this._img.width / arg1;
        var loc2:*=this._img.height / arg2;
        var loc3:*=arg1 * arg2;
        this._imgNodes = [];
        var loc4:*=0;
        var loc5:*=0;
        while (loc5 < arg1) 
        {
            loc6 = 0;
            while (loc6 < arg2) 
            {
                loc7 = new flash.geom.Rectangle(loc5 * loc1, loc6 * loc2, loc1, loc2);
                loc8 = new flash.display.BitmapData(loc1, loc2, true);
                loc8.copyPixels(this._img.bitmapData, loc7, this.zero);
                loc9 = new flash.display.Bitmap(loc8);
                loc9.x = loc5 * (loc1 + arg3);
                loc9.y = loc6 * (loc2 + arg3);
                var loc11:*;
                this._imgNodes[loc11 = loc4++] = loc9;
                loc10 = new flash.display.Sprite();
                loc10.mouseChildren = false;
                this.brickArray.push(loc10);
                loc10.addChild(loc9);
                this._tiledImg.addChild(loc10);
                ++loc6;
            }
            ++loc5;
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: In the remove function, you know this line of code: var loc2:*=this.ballMC.x - this.ballMC.x % 30; sets loc2 to this.ballMC.x - the remainder of this.ballMC.x / 30. Just making sure. Also in the remove function you never call a .removeChild(arg1), so are you trying to remove the Display Object or do you want to change it into something else?

Comment: Also, I'm not that interested in trawling through your untyped, undescriptively-named variables to figure out what you are intending. Consider typing your variables with what you're planning to put in them and giving them descriptive names. And who knows, maybe the compiler will even tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make it shrink in size so that it becomes too small to see.  I don't want them to immediately disappear.  Right now they shrink into the corner of the square.  Sometimes though, they don't shrink.  

Amy, the compiler isn't finding problems because technically the code isn't broken.  And as I said, the code looks like that because the computer had to decompile it.

Comment: Its "untyped, undescriptively-named" because its decompiled code.

Answer (score 0):

I may miss the mark here as its quite hard to read that lot, however, this is my suggestion for your removeMc function. I noticed you have TweenMax, so I would utilise that as opposed to the flash tweener class.

```
 public function removeMC(arg1:flash.display.Sprite):*
    {
       this.score --;
        this.uiBar.txtScore.text=this.score;
        var loc1:*=new flash.geom.ColorTransform();
        loc1.color = 0xffffFF;
        arg1.transform.colorTransform = loc1;
        var loc2:*=this.ballMC.x - this.ballMC.x % 30;
        var loc3:*=this.ballMC.y - this.ballMC.y % 30;

        TweenMax.to(arg1, 0.4, {scaleY:0, scaleX:0, x:loc2, y:loc3, colorTransform:{tint:0x0000ff, tintAmount:1}, onComplete:tweenComplete(arg1)});

       // trace("Ball x:" + this.ballMC.x + " ballY:" + this.ballMC.y + " block x:" + loc2 + " block y:" + loc3);

        this.brickArray.splice(this.indexSearch(this.brickArray, arg1), 1);
        return;
    }

private function tweenComplete(square:Sprite):void
{
    this.removeChild(square);
}
```

That should result in the square shrinking to 0 size and becoming white at the same time. Then once it completes it will remove the child completely.